# Best way to encrypt and decrypt sensitive data in .net 1.1

Tags: encryption, .net-1.1

I'm looking for solution for how can I encrypt and then decrypt sensitive data in .net 1.1 (C#).

I already found good functions around the web but these not compatible with 1.1 platform.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use DES algorithm in .net 1.1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.DES(v=vs.71).aspx